# Is there a way to easily handle json tree data in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, web-scraping

Is there a way how to handle json data trees in python.
Lets say my json tree looks like this:

```py
    "owner": {
          "location": {
                 "longitude":"546561.65101",
                 "city":{
                      "zipcode":"546879",
                      "city":"Boston"
    }}},
```

And my python script looks like this:

```py
import json

with urlopen("example.com/example.json") as response:
    source = response.read()

data=json.loads(source)

#lets say i want to extract specific json data with a for loop

for items in data:
    city=items['HOW CAN I ACCESS THE CITY TAG WITHIN THE PARENT TAGS']
```

Comment: As this is only json/dictionary data, so you can use like items.owner.location.city OR items['owner']['location']['city']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x={
"owner": {
  "location": {
         "longitude":"546561.65101",
         "city":{
              "zipcode":"546879",
              "city":"Boston"
}}}}
```

You can use,

```
x['owner']['location']['city']['city']
```

which will give output as "Boston"